# How to Know Which HTML Element is Causing Vertical Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html). On the getting started menu, there are few templates given. I am playing with that. One example is about fixed Footer. I used nav from previous example and wanted to adjust that with fixed footer. But vertical scrollbar is coming. **I am looking for element which is causing Vertical Scroll Bar.**

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">

            /* Sticky footer styles
            -------------------------------------------------- */

            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
            }

            /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
            #wrap {
                min-height: 100%;
                height: auto !important;
                height: 100%;
                /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
                margin: 0 auto -60px;
            }

            /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
            #push,
            #footer {
                height: 60px;
            }
            #footer {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
            }

            /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
            @media (max-width: 767px) {
                #footer {
                    margin-left: -20px;
                    margin-right: -20px;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                    padding-right: 20px;
                }
            }



            /* Custom page CSS
            -------------------------------------------------- */
            /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

            .container {
                width: auto;
                max-width: 680px;
                height: auto;
            }
            .container .credit {
                margin: 20px 0;
            }

            /* Adjust Nav */
            #wrap > .container {
                margin-top: 60px;
            }

        </style>

        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">

                <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
                <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

            </div> <!-- /container -->
            <div id="push"></div>
        </div> <!-- End Wrap -->

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Le javascript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js-ext/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Is there any trick, which works in these cases to know which Element is causing Scroll Bar?** I faced similar problem earlier, I do not remember if I could find the easy solution.

Comment: The best way I find to figure out issues of this nature is to go into the inspector and start deleting elements until the scrollbar is gone.

Comment: @Conqueror Exactly 10 mins ago I also posted the same answer. But Thanks. Looking for more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got that if I change from *margin-top* to *padding-top* for container to adjust for nav then problem is solved. 
I reached to the solution after deleting elements in Firebug. So, quick fix problem is solved but my questions are still open.

How to know which element is causing scroll bar? Any trick?

Also, why margin-top is not working but padding-top has worked?

To make clear where I made change, I am adding the modified CSS:

```
   /* Adjust Nav */
    #wrap > .container {
        padding-top: 60px;

    }
```

Comment: try adding clear:both; to your css, it will make margin-top work

Comment: @NizamKazi where? I tried in #wrap {} and #wrap > .container {}.

Comment: apply it to element you intended to give margin from top. Means if you want to apply top margin to .container add clear:both css property to it. Also try "float:left" or "float:right" if it is not disturbing alignment of your site.

Answer (score 135):

Add:

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Then when you scroll down you should see one really tall box. Right click on it and select inspect element. That should give you the information you need.

Comment: I have posted the answer below but re-created the problem to check this. It is not making clear where the problem is! at least in the above example.

Answer (score 63):

Paste the below in the console and scroll. It will log the culprit in the console.

```js
function findScroller(element) {
    element.onscroll = function() { console.log(element)}

    Array.from(element.children).forEach(findScroller);
}

findScroller(document.body);
```

Answer (score 23):

There is an [excellent article](https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/) by Chris Coyier which explain everything you need about this problem.

after reading this article, I personally use this code in my console to find out which element cause vertical scroll:

press `F12` in your Browser then choose `console` and paste the below code there and press enter:

```js
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), i = 0, rect, docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
for (; i < all.length; i++) {
    rect = all[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.right > docWidth || rect.left < 0){
        console.log(all[i]);
        all[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
}
```

**Update:**
**if** the above code didn't work it might be an element inside an iframe that make the page to vertically scroll.
in this case you can check `iframes` with this code:

```js
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for(var i=0; i < frames.length; i++){
   var frame = frames[i];
   frame = (frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument);
   var all = frame.document.getElementsByTagName("*"),rect,
       docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
   for (var j =0; j < all.length; j++) {
       rect = all[j].getBoundingClientRect();
       if (rect.right > docWidth || rect.left < 0){
           console.log(all[j]);
           all[j].style.border = '1px solid red';
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the CSS code i was able to know that bootstrap's `row` class was overflowing, adding `m-0` solved it ( Bootstrap v5 )

Answer (score 9):

I'd say you should use [`document.scrollingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement).

Comment: This looks like the way to go, although you'll need a fallback for IE anything. https://caniuse.com/#feat=document-scrollingelement

Answer (score 1):

I find it's usually an image without a max-width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

The below code helps you to find which element is causing vertical or holizon scroll bar.

This will find the element and create border with red:5px at the element of causing the scroll bar.

After run this in the devtool of your browser , check if any element has '_____target' class which is causing the scroll bar.

If you find the element, then comment out this tag from html and refresh and try it again.

```
/* Parameter should be either horizon OR vertical */
let checktype = 'horizon';



(function(which){
    style();

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
    var found = false;

    elements.forEach(element => {
        if( found ) return;
        element.classList.add("_____zerospace");

        var scrollbar = detectScrollbar(element);
        if(!scrollbar[which])
        {
            console.log(element);
            element.classList.add('_____target');
            found = true;
        }
    })

    return;

    function detectScrollbar(target)
    {
        //var div = document.getElementById('container_div_id');
        var element = document.scrollingElement;
        var hasHorizontalScrollbar = element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
        var hasVerticalScrollbar = element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;

        return {horizon: hasHorizontalScrollbar, vertical: hasVerticalScrollbar};
    }

    function style()
    {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerHTML = '._____zerospace { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important } ._____target{border: solid 5px red}';

        document.head.appendChild(style);

    }

})(checktype)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried the other debugging methods and nothing helped. But I found this article, and it's what I'm looking for!

[How to find the cause of horizontal scrollbars](https://polypane.app/blog/strategies-for-dealing-with-horizontal-overflows/)

> ### Setting the width of the body to `100vw`
>
> The viewport width unit (`vw`) is a useful way to make things a certain percentage of the screen wide.
>
> When you use `100vw` however, you make something the full width of the viewport and this **includes the width of scrollbars**. So the end result is that your page is slightly wider than the available width (which is the full width of the viewport **without the scrollbars**).
>
> In short: if you use `width: 100vw` on a page that has a vertical scrollbar you end up with a horizontal overflow.
>
> The easy fix is to use `width: 100%` instead. Percentages don't include the width of the scrollbar, so will automatically fit.
>
> If you can't do that, or you're setting the width on another element, add `overflow-x: hidden` or `overflow: hidden` to the surrounding element to prevent the scrollbar.

After reading this, I checked, and the horizontal overflow was exactly the width of the vertical scrollbar! Searched for `100vw` in the code and found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find it was to scroll down, and then run the following JQuery code in the console:

```
function navigateTree($element) {
    if ($element.scrollTop() > 0)
        console.log($element.prop("tagName") + ": " + $element.scrollTop());
    $element.children().each((i, o) => {
        navigateTree($(o));
    });
}
navigateTree($("html"));
```

The element with the scroll value will have its tag printed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a hidden sub-element had `position: absolute` and was rendering relative to the `body` and outside the ancestor with `overflow: auto`

Answer (score -4):

Use some browser debugging tool. Hit `F12` to open it and check the dom elements. You'll be able to find it.