# Getting Snap Scrolling to work in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck getting [snap scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/) to work in Wordpress? I notice there is a [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348347/is-it-possible-to-use-snap-scrolling) from 5 years on WPD SE that didn't get any answers.

I'm working with the Divi theme. [This](https://spacebetweenthegaps.com/new-home) is my test page.

I used [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60903901/1309582) to find which element owns the scrollbar. The element is `body`.

So I tried the following custom CSS code...

```
body {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; 
}
```

Then, in the child div I want to snap to I've added:

```
scroll-snap-align: start;
```

This didn't work. So I tried setting `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` instead for `#page-container`, and then for `#et-boc` which are the two child elements of `body` that are also just the height of the viewable area. This didn't work either.

I've managed to get snap scrolling working in [a CodePen](https://codepen.io/clayrav/pen/MWKxMKj), so I know that my code is, in theory, correct.

Any ideas anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked page doesn't work anymore and your CodePen is different from what you are describing (classes added to divs instead of body). But this worked for my WordPress installation:

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden; /* Makes sure there is no scroll bar added for the html element */  
}

body {
  height: 100vh; /* Body as high as viewport */
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Add scroll bar for content outside of viewport */
}

.scroll-target, nav { /* Make sure also to add nav and footer to make them reachable by scrolling */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.scroll-target {
  padding-top:20px;
}

nav {
  padding-bottom:20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 200px
}

footer {
  scroll-snap-align: end;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

div.scroll-target {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <nav>This is a navigation</nav>
  <div class="scroll-target" style="background-color:red">This is a div</div>
  <div class="scroll-target" style="background-color:green">This is a div</div>
  <div class="scroll-target" style="background-color:yellow">This is a div</div>
  <div class="scroll-target" style="background-color:pink">This is a div</div>
  <footer>This is a footer </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also be possible using a plugin like [Plus Addons](https://theplusaddons.com/elementor/) they call this feature [full page scroll](https://theplusaddons.com/elementor/widgets/best-page-scrolling-options-for-elementor/full-page/#fp_sec_1). Basically it's definig sections that work as independent full screen parts. Be careful with responsiveness using these.

Comment: Thanks @Rimbok, however it looks like the Plus Addons are specifically for Elementor, not Divi.